# Hg: How to mark a changeset as 'stable'

Tags: mercurial

As the [repository of hg itself](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg), some changesets are marked with `'stable'`. I am wondering how to add the `'stable'` mark to changesets. I had googled but it doesn't help. I tried `'hg help tag'` but still can not figure out how to do it. Do I miss something very basic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe they are not "marked" as stable.

Those commits are part of the **branch 'stable'** history.

[image]

See the graph:

[image]

Comment: @yoco: you are welcome and that was certainly *not* a stupid question ;) I am not yet used to the web mercurial interface myself, so I had to check.

Comment: Note to self: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674063/mercurial-graph-colors/3674139#3674139

Answer (score 2):

This is *named branch*, not tag. hg help branch, or better read Mercurial Book: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html