# Mercurial graph colors

Tags: mercurial

What does it mean for different segments of the graph in the Mercurial Repository Explorer to have different colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly to help distinguishing the branches and their merges, including **merges from anonymous branches** (See [A Guide to Branching in Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial//)).

For instance, for the named branch 'stable', [you will see](http://selenic.com/repo/hg-stable/graph/b10b07a821c3):

[image]

Comment: Why did you circle the things you did on the diagram?

Comment: @Casebash: to illustrates all those commits are part of 'stable' branch (one local, one fetched) the second 'stable' branch has been merge in the local 'stable' branch. Each time a branch starts from local 'stable' branch, that later branch change color.